# Time picker spinner not showing am pm in capital latter in android

Tags: android, timepicker

*Time picker spinner not showing am as AM and pm As PM in capital latter so how to show this in capital latter*
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add some of your code, where you define the time picker in XML and how do you display it in your code.

Comment: <TimePicker
                    android:id="@+id/timepicker"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                  android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/size21"
                    android:theme="@style/TimePickerStyle"
                    android:timePickerMode="spinner" />